# Output Include Paths and CMake

Tags: path, include, makefile, cmake

I would like to force CMake to provide verbosity in terms of include paths (`-I...`). Consider current output:

```
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -DQT_DEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -fopenmp -g3 -gdwarf-2 @CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/go.dir/main.cpp.obj -c /D/Users/Haroogan/Development/Workspace/New2/main.cpp
```

Everywhere, instead of showing a list of include paths, it rather shows `@CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp`. Indeed, this file contains include paths.

How can I force CMake or Make or whatever to output include paths?

Comment: Note that when using MinGW you can also look at the produced output: Somewhere in build-dir\YourProject\CMakeFiles\YourProject.dir will be two files 'link.txt' and 'flags.txt' containing the linker and compiler flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_INCLUDES 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Unix Makefiles (which it looks like you are) you can get the full set of command line flags by typing,

```
 make VERBOSE=1
```

I think some of the other generators also have a cache variable that can be set.

Comment: I've tried both `VERBOSE=1` and `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)`, but `@CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp` continues to appear instead of include path list.

Comment: **NOTE:** using MSYS Makefiles

Comment: I haven't used the MSYS Makefiles - I will see if I can get to the bottom of this as I thought it would work there.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `@CMakeFiles/go.dir/includes_CXX.rsp` is in fact what is passed to the compiler, which then reads this file and interprets it as a list of options. See man gcc for description of this mechanism.

The mechanism is used because shells on MS Windows have a limit to the length of the command line which can be easily exceeded in complex compilation calls. Therefore it is much safer to use files to pass parameters